# Navigating between UITextFields within UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

In the Contacts app's add/edit view, if you hit the 'Return' key in a field, you cycle through each of the UITextFields. These fields seem to be inside a UITableViewCell. What's a good way to do this?

When I have a series of UITextFields not inside a Table, I can invoke 
`[self.view viewWithTag:tag]` to get a list of the views and the use that to cycle through them. But within a table, I only get one view and I'm not sure how to convert this over.

```
 -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Find the next entry field
    for (UIView *view in [self entryFields]) {
        if (view.tag == (textField.tag + 1)) {
            [view becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

/*
 Returns an array of all data entry fields in the view.
 Fields are ordered by tag, and only fields with tag > 0 are included.
 Returned fields are guaranteed to be a subclass of UIResponder.

 From: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/uitextfield
 */
- (NSArray *)entryFields {
    if (!entryFields) {
        self.entryFields = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSInteger tag = 1;
        UIView *aView;
        while (aView = [self.view viewWithTag:tag]) {
            if (aView && [[aView class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIResponder class]]) {
                [entryFields addObject:aView];
            }
            tag++;
        }
    }
    return entryFields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered this while browsing for something myself - sorry for the delay.

If you haven't resolved the issue, you could create an array of uitextfield objects in the same order presented on screen.  As you create the table, set the .tag property of the text field.  Within the text field delegate method - read the tag, increment by 1 (to move to the next field), and issue the becomefirstresponder call.

You could also look at the textFieldDidEndEditing delegate method.